# How can I run a method everytime I get a connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a pretty simple ASP.net razor website. How can I run a method/function to, for example, check the IP of a client every time they send my server a request? It has multiple pages, so I can't just put it in the index's `OnGet()`.

Comment: You can use an [ActionFilter](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/action-filters-in-mvc)

Comment: From what I've understood, I just make the class and the function will automatically be called without registering it anywhere?

Comment: Not exactly: you define an Attribute Class and then add the Attribute to your Methods manually or register it as global.

Comment: How can I register it as global? I'm sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: That depends on the version asp.net mvc that you are using. This is how it is done with asp.net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution